# FD_SIZE and Maximum Number of Sockets an Application Can use in Windows

Tags: sockets, winsock, winsock2, winsockets

I am using a streaming server on windows which is hitting the 32 stream limit. Based on following article on msdn http://support.microsoft.com/kb/111855 we found out that reason is FD_SET size which is defaulted to 64 in winsock.

After increasing FD_SET size to 128 we are able to stream more channels.

The question is,
1. Is it safe to increase FD_SET size?
2. Does increasing FD_SET size guarantees socket availability?
3. Can FD_SIZE be set dynamically or only at compile time? Can we find what is max limit programmatically?

Thanks.
M...

Comment: These questions are all answered in the MSDN article you cited.

Comment: That KB article is **ancient**. It was written for NT Workstation 3.1. Are you sure the same limits apply in Winsock2.h ?

Comment: thanks. based on msdn The default value in Winsock2.h is also 64. first two questions are kind of answered in article but i wanted to know practical observations if any.

Answer (score 0):

In windows I have been successful in setting FD_SETSIZE to 32767.